# What is the proper syntax for piping a command into mysql on powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have a mysql command (Which I have verified is proper syntax) for loading a CSV file into my database, namely

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$DoublePath\\tempFiles\\preupload.csv' INTO TABLE $DataTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '`"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Where $DoublePath is part of the path (I have verfied it is correct) and $DataTable is my table name.
When I run this in the mysql console, it runs exactly as expected loading everything into the database without issue, however, when I try to run this command through powershell, various things happen depending on how I do it.

If I execute it by using --execute (or -e) with this syntax:

```
& mysql -u $Username -h $Address --password=$Password $Database --execute="`"$SQLUploadString`""
```

Then MySQL says that the usage is incorrect and shows me the usage page

When I run it like this:

```
& echo `"$SQLUploadString`" | mysql -u $Username -h $Address --password=$Password $Database
```

Then mysql states:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown MySQL server host 'IGNORE' (0)
```

This issue has been driving me up the wall for almost a week now and I would love it if I could get some insight as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to simply write the command to a file, then pipe the file into mysql, like so:

```
& echo "$SQLUploadString" > $LocalPath\cmd.txt
& cat $LocalPath\cmd.txt | mysql -u $Username -h $Address --password=$Password $Database
```

Comment: Driving you mad for a week, answered it yourself 22 minutes after posting. Fwiw it's not clear to me how or where you had the string - you have `ENCLOSED BY '\`"'` the backtick implies your command is in a PowerShell double quoted string already - but then why do you wrap it in double quotes for `--execute=` instead of `--execute="$SqlUploadString"` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The command actually was in a double quoted string, I just didn't include that part in the post. I initialized it as $SQLUploadString = "<command>". I wrapped it in double quotes for --execute as I wasn't sure if --execute needed the command string in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE ...
```

The problem is here. You need to escape the line terminator string: otherwise the shell will escape-process them, which it did, so the following IGNORE was seen as a new line and therefore a new MySQL command.

Comment: But those are not PowerShell line terminators because PS uses backticks not backslashes - and doesn't process special characters in single quoted strings either..?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The evidemce is against you.

Comment: [here is the PowerShell source code for the tokenizer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/02b5f357a20e6dee9f8e60e3adb9025be3c94490/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/tokenizer.cs#L3732) and it parses ScanStringLiteral with single quotes which is lines 1876-1907 and has no special escape char handling except c# literal char 0 or doubled up single quotes, or ScanStringExpandable with double quotes lines 1999-2054 which has scanning for backticks and no scaning for backslashes (again except c# literal char 0).

Comment: Or maybe [the powershell language spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389), section 2.3.5.2 "*verbatim-string-part: Any Unicode character except single-quote-character*" and "*expandable-string-part: Any Unicode character except $, double-quote-character ` (The backtick character U+0060)*" - no mention of special handling of backslashes in either string type.